# How to setup my localhost server so that I don't have to enter the port number to surf the site?

Tags: php, server, iptables, portforwarding

I started a server inside my PC and when I want to visit localhost with a browser I have to write
localhost:8080
When I am trying to enter in the site with another PC or Phone through WIFI I have to write something like:
192.168.0.123:8080
My question is, is there any way I can enter inside the site I am hosting inside my PC without writing the port, like:
192.168.0.123
(N.B. : I just want to use this inside my wifi network. Going public is not my target)

Comment: The default port for HTTP is `80` ([source]https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#HTTP_session()), so you have to run your server on the `80` port instead of `8080`. Or redirect the `8080` port to `80`.

Comment: Are you using IIS on this? version? Have more details?

Comment: You have to explain what server you use, how you configured it so that it turns on the `8080` port, etc. Otherwise nobody can help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With http, unless the port is 80, you have to specify it.

So you'll have to configure your server to use port 80 instead of 8080.

Comment: How do you do it? If you don't give a solution, this is more a comment than an answer.

Comment: With information provided, eg. "a server" - nobody can give him an answer. Changing / rerouting it from a router or firewall is not the correct way if he can just configure the "server" correctly. His server could be Apache, IIS or any number of http-servers. He doesn't even tell us his OS...

Comment: *nobody can give him an answer* Then don't post an answer, add a comment or flag the question as unclear.

Comment: The answer is "change your port from 80 to 8080", his specific question was: "My question is, is there any way I can enter inside the site I am hosting inside my PC without writing the port, like: 192.168.0.123". He did **not** ask **how** to change it. Do not downvote me just because you cannot read the actual question.

Comment: You're trying to help this user and that's nice, but you can expect downvotes on answers to bad question: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255462/2257664

Comment: It's not a bad question per se, just a bit of a FAQ - sure. Until he clarifies it to include the "how to do it" part, I'm content to give him the benefit of the doubt that he knows how to do it and just tell the answer to the "what to do" -part.

Comment: @DocWeird As AL said, I salute you for being so helpful. But your answer pops up in the low-quality review stack, so your helpfulness could actually backfire in this case. Make it a habit to answer clear questions or ask the OP for extra clarification. Nothing personal, that's just how this site works. In essence, if the score of a question is negative, the best way to help the OP is by telling him how to ask a good question in the first place.

Comment: i was unable to start my wordpress server because there was port number in home url then i used 80 port and its starting like a charm that really helped i dont know why this post have all negetive :( sad life